# Deconstruct "on:change" event in Svelte 3

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have multiple `input` elements that I deconstruct an object onto like such.

```
<script>
    const settings = { value: '', class: 'input'};
</script>
<input {...settings} />
<input {...settings} />
<input {...settings} />
```

Which works fine and I'm very happy with. But I also want to add a shared `on:change` event like this.

```
<script>
    const settings = { value: '', class: 'input', "on:change": () => {}};
</script>
<input {...settings} />
<input {...settings} />
<input {...settings} />
```

Any ideas on how to get that "on:change" to be shared across all the inputs without having to bind each individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this: https://svelte.dev/repl/96452415187144eeb1ab3a70be23b535?version=3.4.1

But using `onchange` instead of `on:change` does come with some disadvantages such as not being able to use modifiers (`on:change|preventDefault`, `on:change|once`, etc).

You could also wrap your input in a component like this: 
https://svelte.dev/repl/2ea820dd4a0b4fedbb7642bd8c1710d2?version=3.4.1

Or do something like this (which to me seems closer to a real-world scenario): https://svelte.dev/repl/caee89041bc44575a8c6fd91b78ca2e6?version=3.4.1

Comment: thanks for this. You wouldn't happen to know what's happening under the hood in Svelte when it binds with `on:` do you?

Comment: `on:` invokes the svelte internal function `listen` which uses `addEventListener` to subscribe to events.  Using `on:` will also guarantee that your event listener will be removed when the component is removed/destroyed.